# How do I make it so my quiz lets me answer?

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

I am a beginning programmer, and I am trying to write a simple program that asks a question then prompts you for an answer to that question in the form of entering "A", "B", or "C" in the input dialog, but no dialog box is appearing.  Everything else seems to work fine.

Here is my code:

```
package homework;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


    int x = 0;
    String[] quizQuestion = {"What is the color of the sky?", "What is the         
        color of the sea?", "What is the color of the earth?"};
    int score = 0;
    String correct = "You are correct";
    String incorrect = "You are incorrect";
    String playerAnswerString = " ";
    playerAnswerString.toUpperCase();
    char playerAnswer = playerAnswerString.charAt(0);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test Your Knowledge!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select an answer to the questions.");
    for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, quizQuestion[x]);
        while(quizQuestion.equals(0))
        {
            playerAnswerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A = Blue, B = Green, C = Brown");
            if(playerAnswer == 'A')
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, correct);
                score++;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incorrect);
            }
        }
        while(quizQuestion.equals(1))
        {
            playerAnswerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A = Blue, B = Green, C = Brown");
            if(playerAnswer == 'B')
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, correct);
                score++;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incorrect);
            }
        }
        while(quizQuestion.equals(2))
        {
            playerAnswerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A = Blue, B = Green, C = Brown");
            if(playerAnswer == 'C')
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, correct);
                score++;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incorrect);
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You scored " + score + "/3.");


}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edited for clarity.

Comment: what is your question?Isnt this working as desired or showing errors?

Comment: what are you using 'while(quizQuestion.equals(0))' for?

Comment: @javaBeginner, the program isn't popping an input dialog to answer the question.

Comment: whats the problem? the question isnt clear

Comment: @ChrisLong i dont have any expereince in swing but I can try to help you.Look into the answers provided below.If any problems are there then ask them.If still you dont get satisfied then you can let me know.i will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few modifications done, please check and let me know if code works as per your expectations.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


    int x = 0;
    String[] quizQuestion = {"What is the color of the sky?", "What is the       color of the sea?", "What is the color of the earth?"};
    int score = 0;
    String correct = "You are correct";
    String incorrect = "You are incorrect";
    String playerAnswerString = " ";
    playerAnswerString.toUpperCase();
    char playerAnswer = playerAnswerString.charAt(0);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test Your Knowledge!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select an answer to the questions.");
    for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, quizQuestion[x]);
        if(x==0)
        {
            playerAnswerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A = Blue, B = Green, C = Brown");

            System.out.println(playerAnswerString+"   "+playerAnswer);

            if(playerAnswerString.equals("A"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, correct);
                score++;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incorrect);
            }
        }
        if(x==1)
        {
            playerAnswerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A = Blue, B = Green, C = Brown");
            if(playerAnswerString.equals("B"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, correct);
                score++;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incorrect);
            }
        }
        if(x==2)
        {
            playerAnswerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A = Blue, B = Green, C = Brown");
            if(playerAnswerString.equals("C"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, correct);
                score++;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, incorrect);
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You scored " + score + "/3.");


}
}
```

Comment: Welcome @ChrisLong. One thing i did't understand in earlier code was use of while loop ( while(quizQuestion.equals(0))). This loop keeps on repeating question till it's not answered correctly. Changed that logic too..

Comment: I believe I was over thinking it, I am still very new at this.  I have less than a month of experience at this.

Answer (score 5):

```
char playerAnswer = playerAnswerString.charAt(0);
```

you have to assign the value of playerAnswer after the user has chosen his answer here

```
playerAnswerString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A = Blue, B = Green, C = Brown");
```

otherwise the variable playerAnswer will be empty

Comment: I hope this is the problem you're looking for